# C# compiler in assembly

Tags: c#, .net, assembly, compiler-construction

I'm currently trying to make an operating system in assembly. I was curious as to if it were possible to create a C# compiler that runs in assembly and loads the C# files as the OS.

For example, within the bootloader is the compiler, and the OS kernel is made in C#. But the bootloader compiles the c# kernel files, and allows them to run without a windows subsidiary.

Is this possible or feasible to do?

Comment: The answer is "Yes" but it would take a great deal of effort... Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Sounds like [singularity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/singularity/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cosmos](https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos) is great, its a kernal made to be programmed with c#, it's missing some key features right now though.